# How can I store JSON in a MySQL database table field?

Tags: mysql, json, database

I currently have an application that uses a third party API whose endpoints return JSON. When a component on the front-end is mounted, I execute a function which makes a GET request to my own back-end and in return my back-end makes a GET request to the third party API, then the response from the API is returned as JSON to the front-end.

I have a limited amount of allowed requests to that API so I want to make sure to save the response to my database so that when a future requests are made, my back-end would return what's in my database instead of making a whole new GET request.

I'm not sure if storing JSON is wise or possible and this is why I decided to ask. Under what data type should the JSON be saved and would there be any drawbacks to what I'm doing?

Comment: JSON is text! Text is stored in a database ALL THE TIME

Comment: I believe that you may use the MySQL JSON functions against a plain text column (though there is a JSON type), so you may just store the JSON as text.  As to whether you would _want_ to do this would depend on a number of things.  JSON represents potentially unnormalized data.

Comment: Of course you also have a JSON column type which you could use if you are using MySQL5.7+

Comment: Oh wow, I did check for a JSON column type before posting this but I found none. Turns out I'm on 5.6.34 MySQL version, I guess that's the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can save JSON to mysql database. Mysql added the JSON datatype above 5.7 version.

Please refer  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. MySQL implements JSON datatype since 5.7 version.

If You are asking about technical details about how to operate with this datatype, here is [excellent shortcut](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

Just quoting few examples:

CREATING:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE facts (sentence JSON);
```

INSERTING:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO facts VALUES
     >   ('{"mascot": "Our mascot is a dolphin named \\"Sakila\\"."}');
```

READING:

```
mysql> SELECT sentence->"$.mascot" FROM facts;
```

But I bet that a real question is about how wise it is to store a JSON in database.

So the general answer is:

`if developers of particular RDBMS included such aproach in their implementation, it is intended and desired for use.`

So, as long as it is good idea to format your data as a JSON at all, it should be also a good idea to store this data in JSON column in RDBMS. I do not have an experience in that particular implementation (prefer Postgresql rather than MySQL), but I had started using JSON datatype as soon as I've needed it and still I do not consider it as a bad decision or something.

Epecially, when you consider storing JSON formated data inside a file and hooking just paths inside database, using a JSON type instead should be a good idea. Almost always storing JSON formated data in files WILL be slower than inserting and querying JSON, Especially, when You need access only to a particular key-value pairs (you can query just a particular keys in ordinary selects).

HOWEVER, when Your data is not inteded to be stored as a JSON format AT ALL, it will be a bad idea to use a JSON datatype also. What kind of data does JSON not like? Basically, all sorts of unstructured streams, when a `number-of-keys :TO: overall-size` ratio is very small. An example would be a dictionary with one key, and value storing 500 kByte long string:

```
{"file": "a very very very ... long string, perhaps just encoded file"}
```

In such case - yes, a better aproach is to store it as a regular files.

So as always, it all depends on a particular use case :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save JSON response inside the table itself.

But It will be in simple string format and parsing of JSON string required to be done at code level.

You can use CLOB for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It would just be a BLOB and theres nothing inheriently wrong with that, its a supported datatype.

However, i would urge you to save the JSON to a file and keep a list of paths instead. simply because it will be quicker.